# Monitoring Tool for checking files in a directory

Tags: bash, scripting

I have four files which come in to this directory C:/Desktop/Folder each day which are in the following format:

```
DD/MM/YYYY/HH/MM/SS/File
```

Examples:

```
01/01/2018/01:01:00
01/01/2018/01:02:00
01/01/2018/01:03:00
01/01/2018/01:04:00
```

I want my script to only email me if in a 24 hour period the 4th file:

01/01/2018/01:04:00 does not come into the mailbox. I cannot do an = as each day the date increments by 1 for example:

01/01/2018/01:01:00 then
02/01/2018/01:01:00

Code:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 monitor_dir=/path/to/dir
 email=me@me.com

 files=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
 IFS=$'\n'

 while true
 do
   sleep 5s

   newfiles=$(find "$monitor_dir" -maxdepth 1 | sort)
   added=$(comm -13 <(echo "$files") <(echo "$newfiles"))

   [ "$added" != "" ] && find $added -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Tc\t%s\t%p\n' | mail -s "incoming" "$email"

   files="$newfiles"
done
```

Can I please have some assistance with how I can alter this code to reflect my new requirements?

Comment: You might want to use this - https://superuser.com/a/959040/707284. The key here is to use `inotifywait`

Comment: I am having some trouble with getting this to work